# how can I animate multiple elements inside a v-for loop in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gsap

here's the html

```
<div id="slider" class="slider" @mousedown="startDrag" @mouseup="stopDrag" @mousemove="mouseMoving" @mouseLeave="stopDrag">
    <div class="slider-cards" :style="`transform: translate3d(${cardsX}px,0,0)`">
      <div class="slider-card" @mouseover="sliderCardOver" @mouseout="sliderCardOut" v-for="(slide, index) in slides" :key="index">
          <div class="img-container">
            <img class="slider-card-img" :src="slide.image" :alt="slide.title" draggable="false"/>
          </div>
          <div class="slider-info">
            <h1>{{slide.title}}</h1>
            <p>{{slide.description}}</p>
            <button class="slider-button">Learn More</button>
          </div>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here's the js

```
sliderCardOver(e){
    console.log(e.target)
    TweenMax.to(e.target, .7, {scaleX:1.1, scaleY:1.1, ease:Quad.easeInOut});
    //TweenMax.to('.slider-info h1', .5, {y:'10px', ease:Quint.easeInOut, delay:.2});
},
```

I'm trying to animate with tweenMax, the img element and the h1 and p elements below it. I've tried using index, I've tried making the class name's dynamic, I've tried putting both those div's inside a container div in the hopes that it'd would pick up on that, but nothing has worked so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this: [Vue State Transitions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html)

Comment: appreciate the response, i'll look into this.